# Does stream-chat-react's MessageSimple Component Indicate Edited Messages?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, messaging, getstream-io, getstream-chat

`"stream-chat-react": "^10.8.8"`

#### Description

I am currently using the `stream-chat-react` library to integrate chat functionalities into my application. My application utilizes the `MessageSimple` component for displaying messages. I have encountered a specific question regarding the handling of edited messages.

#### Question

Does the `stream-chat-react` library, specifically the `MessageSimple` component, automatically provide an "Edited" label for messages that have been edited after being sent? Currently, `MessageSimple` renders the message content and the timestamp (e.g., "Today at 6:22 PM") but does not indicate if a message has been edited.

#### Context

In my application, it's important for users to know when a message has been edited after its initial posting. The `MessageSimple` component handles the rendering of messages, including their timestamps, but it does not seem to display any indication of whether the message has been edited. I noticed that messages have `created_at` and `updated_at` timestamps, and I am considering using these to manually implement an "Edited" label. However, before proceeding, I wanted to confirm if such a feature already exists in the `stream-chat-react` library or if there are recommended practices for this.

#### Screenshot

[image]
Attached is a screenshot for reference, showing how messages are currently displayed using the `MessageSimple` component. My aim is to add an "Edited" label next to the timestamp when a message has been modified after its initial creation.

***I want the Edited Label right after the Timestamp something like this `Today at 6:22PM (Edited).`***

### Code Usage

```
import {
  MessageSimple,
  StreamMessage,
  useChannelStateContext,
  useMessageContext,
} from 'stream-chat-react';

export const IamCustomMessage = (): JSX.Element => {
  const { message } = useMessageContext();

  const isMessageEdited =
    message.created_at !== undefined &&
    message.updated_at !== undefined &&
    new Date(message.updated_at).getTime() >
    new Date(message.created_at).getTime();
      
return (
         <div>
               <MessageSimple />
         </div>
    );
}
```

#### Additional Information

I would greatly appreciate any guidance or information regarding this feature. If it's not currently available, could you please advise on the best approach to implement this functionality manually?